# apache kafka MM2 curl command

Tags: curl, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I am running AWS MSK v2.7.0 with SASL/SCRAM. I have an ec2 instance running the kafka connector and mirror maker 2 (MM2).  I was able to start up the distributor w/o any issue but when I run the curl command to start the worker, the output look fine but no data are replicating.  The svc_1 principle has the following permission on both source and target:

TOPICS:

-read
-create
-describe
-describe-configs

GROUPS:
-describe
-read

```
curl -s -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data @/app/kafka/config/worker.json http://host.cloud.domain.com:8083/connectors -v
```

output of the above command:

```
*   Trying 172.x.x.x:8083...
* Connected to host.cloud2.domain.com (172.x.x.x) port 8083 (#0)
> POST /connectors HTTP/1.1
> Host: host.cloud2.domain.com:8083
> User-Agent: curl/7.76.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 1882
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
< Date: Mon, 15 Nov 2021 21:06:52 GMT
< Location: http://host.cloud2.domain.com:8083/connectors/worker-prod-01-mm2-worker
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 1735
< Server: Jetty(9.4.33.v20201020)
< 
{"name":"worker-prod-01-mm2-worker","config":{"connector.class":"org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector","name":"worker-prod-01-mm2-worker","topics":"data.*","tasks.max":"2","source.cluster.alias":"source","target.cluster.alias":"target","source.cluster.bootstrap.servers":"b-1.kafka.uswest-2.amazonaws.com:9096","target.cluster.bootstrap.servers":"b-1.kafka.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:9096","source->target.enabled":"true","target->source.enabled":"false","offset-syncs.topic.replication.factor":"3","topics.exclude":".*[\\-\\.]internal, .*\\.replica, __consumer_offsets","groups.blacklist":"console-consumer-.*, connect-.*, __.*","topic.creation.default.replication.factor":"3","topic.creatio* Connection #0 to host host.cloud2.domain.com left intact
n.default.partitions":"24","key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter","value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter","source.cluster.sasl.mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-512","source.cluster.security.protocol":"SASL_SSL","source.cluster.sasl.jaas.config":"org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=\"svc_1\" password=\"xxx290MM0L\";","target.cluster.security.protocol":"SASL_SSL","target.cluster.sasl.mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-512","target.cluster.sasl.jaas.config":"org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=\"svc_1\" password=\"xxx4WWVuA\";"},"tasks":[],"type":"source"}
```

additionally, when I run:

```
curl -s http://host.cloud2.domain.com:8083/connectors
```

all I get is [].  I'm not seeing any errors in the log either.  can someone let me know what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: How large is the Connect cluster?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out after walking thru my previous steps.  It ended up being the ACL issue.  I started by granting operation all, allow all to Group.  That didn't work.  I changed the topics permission to operation all, allow all.  That worked.